# Can't install Android Studio on Yosemite

Tags: android, android-studio, osx-yosemite

Refresh Sources:

```
  Failed to fetch URL dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: File not found
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Failed to fetch URL dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: File not found
Refresh Sources:
  Failed to fetch URL dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: File not found
```

There is nothing to install or update.
`platform-tools`, `extra-android-m2repository` and 7 more SDK components were not installed

Answer (score 0):

Where are you installing android studio? Googling I find your problem solved here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76268

The solution is:

> Check the permissions of your .android directory. The sdk update process stores a copy of the repository listing xml in .android/cache, which will apparently fail silently if the permissions are incorrect.